# python two for loops in list comprehension with 2 items

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to comprehend two loops in one line with 2 variables, however it is always returning one variable and I don't seem to understand the reason behind it. My code is as follow:

```
text = ['hello, hi', 'goodbye, bye', 'how do you do, howdy']
mapped = {x:y for string in text for x, y in string.split(',')}
```

The error I'm getting:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

How can I adjust my line so that it returns 2 variables instead of one? Or is it just not possible?

I understand that expanded it looks as follows:

```
for string in text:
  for x, y in string.split(','):
    mapped[x] = y
```

I don't understand where I'm going wrong.

Comment: `string.split(',')` returns a list but no a zip or dict.items kind of object. you can iterate over only one variable like x or y and not x,y

Comment: The expanded version should have ``x, y = string.split(',')``, not ``for x, y in string.split(','):``

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reuse an expression in a comprehension expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841652/how-to-reuse-an-expression-in-a-comprehension-expression)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look carefully at the order of operations that you really want - and I think you're just missing some brackets:

```
text = ['hello, hi', 'goodbye, bye', 'how do you do, howdy']
mapped =  {x:y for x, y in [string.split(',') for string in text]}
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found a different way to achieve the same result, but without using double comprehension (which defeats the point in this question). I'm sharing it in case someone wants to know.

```
dict(string.split(',') for string in text)
```

since `x:y for x, y` is redundant it can simply be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

This error arises because `string.split()` is creating a list, which looks like

```
['hello', ' hi']
['goodbye', ' bye']
['how do you do', ' howdy']
```

Now, `for x, y in string.split()` is useless because there aren't 2 values to assign x and y to. There is only 1 list. You can rather try

```
for string in text:
    lis = string.split(',')
    mapped.update({lis[0] : lis[1]})
```

**Output**

{'goodbye': ' bye', 'hello': ' hi', 'how do you do': ' howdy'}