# Is there a way to condense this into a dictionary comprehension?

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I'm trying to condense this down, but I'm getting stuck in trying to implement the regex in the comprehension while iterating over a list.

```
acl_lines = some_list
hash_dict = {}
for line in acl_lines:
    search = re.search(hash_regex, line)
    if search:
        hash_dict[search.group(2)] = search.group(1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reuse an expression in a comprehension expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841652/how-to-reuse-an-expression-in-a-comprehension-expression)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
hash_dict = {
    s.group(2): s.group(1) 
    for s in (re.search(hash_regex, line) for line in acl_lines) if s
}
```

In order not to call `search` twice, you insert an extra generator expression.