# Python 3.7 does not support assignment expressions

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
n = int(input())
a, b, c = map(int, input().split())
result = sum(s // c + 1 for i in range(n) for j in range(n - a * i) if (s := n - a * i - b * j - 1) >= 0)
print(result)
```

But I have an error that Python 3.7 does not support assignment expressions in this part (s := n - a * i - b * j - 1). How can I rewrite it? I want to rewrite it to python3.7

Comment: Walrus operator `:=` was introduced in 3.8

Comment: @JoeFerndz Is it actually called the "walrus" operator?  That's great :-D

Comment: Suggestion - upgrade your Python version.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#:~:text=There%20is%20new%20syntax%20%3A%3D,and%20tusks%20of%20a%20walrus.&text=Try%20to%20limit%20use%20of,reduce%20complexity%20and%20improve%20readability.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reuse an expression in a comprehension expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841652/how-to-reuse-an-expression-in-a-comprehension-expression)

Comment: @RocketHazmat Not officially. I believe that term is pulled from other languages.

Answer (score 0):

The simple, though repetitive, fix is to "inline" the value of `s`.

```
result = sum((n - a * i - b * j - 1) // c + 1 
              for i in range(n) 
              for j in range(n - a * i) if n - a * i - b * j - 1 >= 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with converting the generator expression to plain code and then it is a simple task:

```
result = 0
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n - a * i):
        s = n - a * i - b * j - 1
        if s >= 0:
            result += s // c + 1
```